# Is setLenient in pdfBox in java safe for healing PDF files?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

When I use setLenient property in pdfParser to false, I get the follwoing exception: java.io.IOException: XREF for 5:0 points to wrong object: 4:0 at offset 1013093. However if I set that flag to true the pdf file is parsed without problem.

I would like to know please how does setLenient flag work and wether it is safe to use, I mean, will I have information loss?

Comment: What is the nature of the data corruption? Bit flips? Deletions? Whole 4k sections of data missing? Something else? Simply being lenient about the PDF spec isn't a magical solution to information being missing or irretrievably turned to garbage.

Comment: As we don't have *those corrupted PDF files," how should we tell the best approach to address them specifically? And how should we know whether *correcting without information loss* is possible for them?

Comment: (After your edit) OK, so there appear to be issues with the cross reference table of your pdf. Still there can be many different types of pdf corruption that cause issues there, so without being able to analyze the specific file, one cannot say whether there will be some data loss or not.